# How to say "Take it from me who ..." in casual French?

Tags: expressions

In conversation with my colleague, I said:

> Les légumes et les fruits ne sont pas à mettre dans le même panier ; c'est comme le jour et la nuit !
>
> Les fruits sont réputés riches en vitamines et minéraux, certes, et ils ne font pas monter en flèche le taux de sucre dans le sang. Ça  n'empêche qu‘ils font vieillir la peau plus vite.
>
> {***Take it from me and my girlfriend who...***} ***Crois-moi et ma petite amie***, on s'en passe depuis déjà assez longtemps pour en ressentir les effets salutaires.

This phrase came to mind as a sort of quick fix, but what is a more idiomatic turn of phrase?

In English, you use the expression "Take it from me who …" to point out that the very fact of your experiencing something first-hand should lend some credibility to what you have just said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This expression is often used with the term *expérience*, as in "Crois-en mon expérience, ...".

> *Crois-en notre expérience, ma copine et moi on s'en passe depuis ...*

Comment: You could equally say "Fais-moi confiance, ..." (*trust me*) or "Aie confiance en moi et ma copine, qui nous nous en passons depuis ...".

Comment: @LEI J'aime aussi :-) Bonne variante me semble-t-il.

Comment: @LEI Je dirais plutôt 'ma copine et moi' dans un soucis d'élégance on finit par soi même en général, cela n'a rien de syntaxique ceci dit :)

Comment: @Tensibai Exact, c'est plus poli !

Comment: « Fais-nous confiance, ***car*** on s'en passe ***nous-mêmes*** depuis déjà assez longtemps ..." » Hi. What do you think of adding "car" and "nous-mêmes"? Does "car" sound redundant here? Does "nous-mêmes", on the other hand, serve to emphasise the fact that it comes from our personal experience?

Comment: It depends on how you want to sound, in terms of register. Your proposition sounds clear enough but is probably not very casual. Pushing the cursor slightly towards the "casual" direction (if ever useful), you could try *Fais-nous confiance, **nous** on s'en passe depuis longtemps...* even if it would be slightly "faulty" in written context